# Creating a Virtual Machine on Bluemix, is giving an error while importing ssh key

Tags: ssh, openstack, ibm-cloud

I am following the steps to create Virtual Machine on `Bluemix` following the steps as below.
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/index-gentopic4.html#vm_ssh_key

I am blocked when I am trying to configure a `SSH key`. I am using an existing key pair which I use with my other machines. 
I get an error

```
"Keypair data is invalid: failed to generate fingerprint"
```

I am not sure if it is not happy with the format or it is not OK with the `public key` itself.
I have tried entering with the lines

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ---- , 
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

and without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following [github's steps](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) to create a key pair.  It seems your key pair might be invalid.  Does your keypair work else where?

Comment: My original key-pair does work. However, I created a new on e following Bluemix documentation. I copied the public key right from the puttygen window and the VM creation accepted it. The earlier public key was in my saved text file and guess something was going wrong with the format as I coped from it.